# Adjust the array indices to start at 1 for scoreboard rank

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am using {{@index}} in the HTML to display that players ranking on the list. The problem is it will only display it like this:

0) bob: 15

1) joe: 10

2) sam: 5

3) tim: -10

im using meteor and nodejs
this is my js code

```
var scoreList = PlayersList.find({ createdBy: currentUserId },
                        { sort: {score: -1, name: 1} });
    return scoreList;
```

and heres my HTML

```
    {{#each player}}
<p class="player {{selectedClass}}">{{@index}}) {{name}}: {{score}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to achieve this is to create tiny helper:

```
plusOne(idx) {
  return idx + 1;
}
```

And use it in template:

```
{{plusOne @index}}
```